# EndsWith() not working properly

Tags: c#, .net

I want to add the corresponding index of all the strings in the `tres4` array, if they match the end of the input string. Yet, my list gets filled with all the indexes 1-12, as opposed to only those, matching the end of my input string. Only `1` should be added to my `List` in this case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Encoding
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] tres4 = {
                    "CHU",
                    "TEL", 
                    "OFT",
                    "IVA",
                    "EMY",
                    "VNB",
                    "POQ",
                    "ERI",
                    "CAD",
                    "K-A",
                    "IIA",
                    "YLO",
                    "PLA"
            };

            string message = "CHUTEL";
            List<int> digits = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < tres4.Length; i++)
            {
                if (message.EndsWith(tres4[i]));
                {
                    digits.Add(i);
                }   
            }

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", digits));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon:

```
if (message.EndsWith(tres4[i]));
```

See the semicolon at the end? Remove it and it'll work.

Next time you should give a debugger a try, it would show you the problem right away.

Answer (score 8):

Remove `;` from `if` condition

```
if (message.EndsWith(tres4[i]))
```